# Ajax undifend parameter value returns from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, response

Hello I am using the following function in javascript on asp.net website

```
        function addBrand() {


        var ID = document.getElementById("ID").value;
        var PicLink = document.getElementById('<%= PicLink.ClientID %>').value;
        var Name = document.getElementById('<%= name.ClientID %>').value;
        var Origin = document.getElementById('<%= origin.ClientID %>').value;
        var Sports = document.getElementById('<%= Sports.ClientID %>');
        var Casual = document.getElementById('<%= Casual.ClientID %>');
            var Safety = document.getElementById('<%= Safety.ClientID %>');
            Sports = Sports.checked;
            Casual = Casual.checked;
            Safety = Safety.checked;
        var Type="";
        if (Sports || Sports == "true")
            Type += "Sports";
        if (Casual || Casual == "true")
            Type += " Casual";
        if (Safety || Safety == "true")
            Type += " Safety";
        if (Origin == null || Origin == "" || Type == null || Type == "" || Name == null || Name == ""  || PicLink == null || PicLink == "" || ID == null || ID == "" || ID < 0) {
            alert("One of the fields are empty.. \n Please fill it and try again later.");
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "Handler.ashx?cmd=addBrand&pic=" + PicLink + "&name=" + Name + "&type=" + Type + "&id=" + ID + "&origin=" + Origin,
            async: true,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
           //the response value is always undefiend
                   }


                }


        });
    }
```

You can see where my success function is  I cannot get the response value.
This is my code in the server side:

```
 public void addBrandResult(IAsyncResult result)
{
    System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session = null;

    try
    {
        Carrier c = (Carrier)result.AsyncState;

        SqlConnection cnn = c.myConnect;
        session = c.session;

        int reader = c.myCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
        if (reader == 0)
        {

            session["mode"] = "Can not add the product ! Please try again later.";
            myState._context.Response.Write("FAILED");
        }
        else
        {


            session["mode"] = "Product added successfully ! ";
            myState._context.Response.Write("SUCCESS");
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        session["mode"] = "Can not add the product ! Please try again later.";
        myState._context.Response.Write("FAILED");
    }
 }
```

I also tried using the session["mode"] .to string but again non value available.

Comment: `dataType: "html",` ? Are you expecting `HTML` in response ?

Comment: @Rayon I expecting to get the "SUCCESS" OR "FAILED" that I wrote in the server,also I tried to write json instead of html but still the same problem

Comment: Remove `dataType` and test.. Make sure your page is not getting `unloaded`(`submitted`)..

Comment: @Rayon still same problem

Comment: Check the Console for errors... Also go through the response in `network-tab`